# How can I calculate the fuel required for a specific route and aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-performance, flight-planning, fuel

Okay, I'm writing a online game. I've got two airports and the equipment. For example: Heathrow - LAX on a 744.

What I want to work out is the fuel required, as this will apply a cost to the airline. I know there are many many things such as wind, temperature, regulatory requirements like alternate airport etc but I want something simple.

How can I work out simply the fuel required? Are there charts I can use for working out takeoff, each hour in cruise and descent?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! We have several questions already on calculating fuel burn: [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34183/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8652/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36652/62). If you're new to the site, the [tour] may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want something simple, just look up the average fuel consumption for the aircraft type (in gallons per hour), and multiply that by the duration of the flight. Although airlines have more sophisticated tools to plan refuelling, this is how GA pilots estimate how much fuel there should be in the tank.

Official fuel consumption figures can be hard to get hold of because the Pilots' Operating Handbook and other documentation for the aircraft might not be publicly available, but it's easy to find out rough figures from web forums populated by pilots of that type.

If you are interested in something more complex (and accurate), see [How can I calculate the fuel consumption of an Airbus 320-200 at various loads?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/how-can-i-calculate-the-fuel-consumption-of-an-airbus-320-200-at-various-loads)

Comment: Thanks; I've looked at the average consumption per hour but depending on the length of flight this will vary. For example, a 3-hour flight on a 777 will have a vastly different consumption to an average consumption on a 14-hour flight. I could look up averages for each hour and place them in a table.

Comment: Any recommendations on where to get the Breguet equation explained in an example?

Comment: @kiwis The A320 question that Dan mentions in his answer has an example of using the Breguet equation. If it isn't clear enough for what you need, you might like to ask a new question about it specifically, but please do explain exactly what you're looking for that isn't already answered. Otherwise, people will probably refer you back to the A320 question again.